# what is the best practice when public in-secured microservice need to access secured microservices

Tags: api, .net-core, jwt, microservices

I have a SaaS monolith that I'm migrating to micro-service APIs. 7 out of 9 of the micro-services are secured with JWT. While the other two micro-services should have anonymous access, with results aggregated from the secured micro-services.

I only need to expose 1 action on each anonymous micro-service.

Thanks

Comment: I'm currently exposing two authentication actions one for the use and one for service. the user action accept credential and service action is expecting a key, authentication service is generating JWT based on that key

Comment: You say in the title that the unsecured microservices need to make calls to the JWT secured ones? If that's true, you should consider enforcing the JWT security for the unsecured endpoints as well. If the endpoints need JWT security to do their job, even if security is only needed to call dependencies, then your endpoint needs JWT security too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [client credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) access token to secure the communication between the insecure and the secure micro-service. The secured micro-service will then receive an access token for every request, either an access token issued for a user or an access token issued for a client.